# How do I change this for loop into a function?

Tags: python, function, for-loop

I am trying to find the largest and then second- largest number in a list, then calculate the sum and difference of the two, then print the two solutions in a list.

```
numbers = [1,2,3,4,5]

largest_integer = -1e10
second_largest_integer = -1e11

for item in numbers:
    if item > largest_integer:
        second_largest_integer = largest_integer
        largest_integer = item
    elif item > second_largest_integer:
        second_largest_integer = item
add = int(largest_integer + second_largest_integer)
minus = int(largest_integer - second_largest_integer)
print([add,minus])
```

OUTPUT = [9,1]

Tried many times but failed anyway. Any thoughts?

Comment: `5+4=9`, `5-4=1`. Your results seems right to me.

Comment: I have tested your code with other numbers as well and it seems to run perfectly. What's your problem? How can you help you?

Comment: So, the problem is making this into a function?

Answer (score 0):

This function will take 1 argument, which is list of numbers.

```py
def get_first_and_second_largest(numbers):

    largest_integer = -1e10
    second_largest_integer = -1e11

    for item in numbers:
        if item > largest_integer:
            second_largest_integer = largest_integer
            largest_integer = item
        elif item > second_largest_integer:
            second_largest_integer = item
    add = int(largest_integer + second_largest_integer)
    minus = int(largest_integer - second_largest_integer)

    return [add,minus]


print(get_first_and_second_largest([1,2,3,4,5]))
```